# MagickImage - Cannot read TIFF Image

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I have a TIFF image that I want to read using MagickImage but I keep getting an exception when I create a new instance of the MagickImage class when passing my TIFF image as a parameter.

```
public MagickImage ReduceBitDepth(string tFilePathName)
        {        
            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(tFilePathName))
            {
                image.Depth = 3;            
                return image;
            }
        }
```

The using statement results in the following error:

**Error fetching directory count. `TIFFAdvanceDirectory' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/654.**

I have tried this method with other image file formats such as JPEG and PNG and it works fine.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the TIFF file you try to open is malformed or corrupted in some way...

Comment: Your `using` will dispose `image`, so `return image` is not going to return anything usable.

Comment: @elgonzo - I've tried multiple different TIFF images but no luck so far.

Comment: @DourHighArch Thanks for that. I've now removed the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```cs
public myClass : IDisposable // to use using()
{
  public MagickImage ReduceBitDepth(string tFilePathName)
  {        
    return new MagickImage(tFilePathName))
    {
      image.Depth = 3;           
    }
  }
}
```

and in your application:

```cs
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
using(MagickImage image = myclass.ReduceBitDepth(filepath))
{
  // ... to use image here
}
```